# Why does this code work on iOS 32 bit but not on 64 bit?

Tags: ios, delphi, xcode7.3, ios9.3, delphi-10.1-berlin

The code below receives MIDI data from a musical instrument connected to the iOS device. It works fine on a 32 bit iOS device. On 64 bit, the callback function is also called for every event, but the data received in 'pktlist' is invalid. What is wrong?

The data I receive in `MidiReadProc` is always the same on a 64 bit device, and it is clearly wrong as the length would normally never be 0:

```
pktlist^.numPackets = 1
lPacket.MIDItimestamp=$E4FE000100000961
lPacket.length=$0000
lPacket.data[0]=$00
```

The Callback function:

```
procedure MidiReadProc(pktlist: MIDIPacketListRef; refCon, connRefCon: Pointer); cdecl;
var
  lPacket: MIDIPacket;
  lPacketRef: MIDIPacketRef;
  j: Integer;
  lPtr: ^Byte;
begin
  lPacketRef := MIDIPacketRef(@(pktlist^.Packet[0]));
  for j := 0 to pktlist^.numPackets-1 do
  begin
    lPacket := lPacketRef^;
    if (lPacket.length > 0) and (lPacket.data[0] <> $F0) then
      //handle data here

    //translation of the MIDIPacketNext Macro:
    lPtr := @lPacketRef^.data[lPacketRef^.length];
    lPacketRef := MIDIPacketRef((UInt64(lPtr) + 3) and (not 3));
  end;
end;
```

In case it could be related to the header translation, here is the translation:

Extract from CoreMIDI.h:

```c
typedef UInt64 MIDITimeStamp;

#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct MIDIPacket
{
    MIDITimeStamp       timeStamp;
    UInt16              length;
    Byte                data[256];
};
typedef struct MIDIPacket           MIDIPacket;

struct MIDIPacketList
{
    UInt32              numPackets; 
    MIDIPacket          packet[1];
};
typedef struct MIDIPacketList MIDIPacketList;
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef void
(*MIDIReadProc)(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *readProcRefCon, void *srcConnRefCon);


#if TARGET_CPU_ARM || TARGET_CPU_ARM64
// MIDIPacket must be 4-byte aligned
#define MIDIPacketNext(pkt) ((MIDIPacket *)(((uintptr_t)(&(pkt)->data[(pkt)->length]) + 3) & ~3))
```

Extract from CoreMIDI.pas (the translation of CoreMIDI.h is made by Pavel Jiri Strnad and [is available here](http://pjstrnad.com/my-projects/delphi-implementation-missing-ios-frameworks/)):

```
MIDITimeStamp = UInt64;

MIDIPacket = record
   timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp;
   length: UInt16;
   data: array [0..255] of Byte;
end;
MIDIPacketRef = ^MIDIPacket;

MIDIPacketList = record
   numPackets: UInt32;
   packet: array [0..0] of MIDIPacket;
end;
MIDIPacketListRef = ^MIDIPacketList;

MIDIReadProc = procedure (pktlist: MIDIPacketListRef; readProcRefCon: pointer; srcConnRefCon: pointer); cdecl;
```

**Update:**

As suggested by David in the comments, here are field offsets of the records:

`MIDIPacketList` offsets:

```
64 bit Align 8: numPackets=0 packet=8 <- this was the one causing problems
64 bit Align 1: numPackets=0 packet=4
32 bit Align 8: numPackets=0 packet=4
32 bit Align 1: numPackets=0 packet=4
```

`MIDIPacket` offsets:

```
64 bit Align 8: timeStamp=0 length=8 data=10
64 bit Align 1: timeStamp=0 length=8 data=10
32 bit Align 8: timeStamp=0 length=8 data=10
32 bit Align 1: timeStamp=0 length=8 data=10
```

Comment: I don't want to start a tag war, but this really has nothing to do with firemonkey.

Comment: Did you verify the structure alignment is correct?

Comment: This is absolutely nothing to do with FireMonkey. It's an interop question. I know nothing about FireMonkey but lots about interop. Would you like me to ignore it because I'm not a FireMonkey dev?

Comment: You are right, it has nothing to do with Firemonkey, but only Firemonkey developers will be using the code I present. That is why I think the Firemonkey tag would be relevant, but I am not interested in a tag war either, so if it is important for you to leave Firemonkey developers out, it is fine with me. I just want to solve a code problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you refer to the Delphi Record alignment? It is set to Quad Word (default).

Comment: Check that the layout of the record is correct. That the offsets used by Delphi match those used by the objc compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not sure what you mean? The exact same code works perfectly well on 32 bit, and the Record alignment in Delphi is the same in 32 bit and 64 bit. What else can I check? (I don't know how the Objective C compiler works, so on that side I need some assistance)

Comment: Check that the layout of the record is correct. Are each of the fields at the correct offset.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found that setting `{$Align 1}` at the top of CoreMIDI.pas makes it work on 64 bit (in fact any Align value below 8 works), however on 32 bit only the default 8 byte alignment works. This looks really strange and hacky to me, but I don't understand what is going on, so I currently have no better option.

Comment: Did you check the offsets of the fields? In Obj-C and Delphi?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did it in Delphi and that lead me to setting Align to 1, which solved the problem (and my previous comment about not working on 32 bit was wrong).

Comment: ALIGN 1 gives the same result as packed. Typically I'd want to apply this to specific records. If every record in a header translation is packed, then ALIGN 1 at the top of the header translation unit is sensible. Did you output the offset of the fields yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added field offsets to the question. As I understand your previous comment it is more safe to add `packed`only to the records that specifically require it, as it is not a general requirement?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of those offsets. I would expect to see for each record its size, and then the offset for each member. For instance, I would expect `MIDIPacket` to have size 266, and the member offsets to be 0, 8 and 10.

Comment: The size is not there, but the offsets are there as you expected. What is unclear?

Comment: OK, I was slow on the up take. What matters are the offsets on the ObjC side. What are they? And the header files, do they specify alignment/packing?

Comment: Instead of leaving the question unanswered, put your solution as an answer.

Comment: @LURD Ok, I've done that now, though it was David, who lead me to the solution by asking the right questions.

Comment: That's good. You can give him credit by ticking some other answers of his if you like.

Comment: The Delphi translation of CoreMIDI MIDIServices.h (into MacAPI.CoreMIDI.pas) fails to properly align MIDIPacket and MIDIPacketList. I don't know if these files were included in Delphi when this question was asked, but the question pointed me to the resolution. Adding packed to Delphi's type declaration for these two records fixes the issue. I have reported this as a bug here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I looked further into the `CoreMIDI.h` header file. Though I have never worked with any C languages, I did spot this line: `#pragma pack(push, 4)` above the definition of MIDIPacket (I have now added it to extract in the question), which shows clearly what should be done.

Setting `{$Align 1}` for the whole file was not the correct solution. Instead only the two records (`MIDIPacket` and `MIDIPacketList`) should have 4 byte alignments instead of 8 byte alignment.

Comment: In case anyone gets here the way I did: The official Delphi translations in MacAPI.CoreMIDI.pas incorrectly handle these records. Reported here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31187

Answer (score -1):

C struct must be declared as packed record in delphi. C doesn't align fields in struct's.

Comment: The strange thing is that this does not work on 32 bit, only on 64 bit.

Comment: I take my previous comment back. The reason it did not work on 32 bit was something else. It now works on both 32 bit and 64 bit. The question is now if there is any difference between adding `packed` to each record or to add {$Align 1} at the top...

Comment: I'd be pleased to mark your answer as the correct answer. However, I find it strange that none of the 26 translations of framework headers included with Delphi uses neither `packed`or Align1.

Comment: By default C compilers will align fields. When you pack a record, that means that you have unaligned fields.